# InputData1 variable is not taking the vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to assign the result of a vlookup to a variable but the vlookup value is actually a user input but is not working.

I do not know what else I can change on my vba code :(

It is showing me a debug error on the vlookup formula

```
        Sub Info()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim inputData, inputData1 As String
Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction: Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim rngLook As Range

Set rngLook = Sheets("AutoZeroDatabase").Range("H1:I12")

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Info")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

inputData = InputBox("Enter a number from 1 to 12 to select a month i.e. 1 for January", "Input Box Text")

inputData1 = wsFunc.VLookup(CInt(inputData), rngLook, 2, False)

table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = inputData1

MsgBox ("Thank you for taking the time to update me :)")

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming you have numbers in cells H1:H12, ensure you convert `inputData` from a `Variant` to an Integer by using `wsFunc.VLookup(CInt(inputData), rngLook, 2, False)`.

Comment: Or use an Application.InputBox instead of just an InputBox, and use the `Type` parameter with a value of 1.

Comment: You're the man :) . Yes the information on that range has numbers on the 1st column and text on the 2nd column . I believe this can be fixed if I change the variable to integer right ?

Comment: (a) Using `wsFunc.VLookup(CInt(inputData), rngLook, 2, False)` would be the **simplest** fix - it coerces the contents of `inputData` to an integer, and that will then be matched against your H1:H12 data.  (But I recommend that you place some validity checks on `InputData` to give proper warnings if the user enters "xyz", or "13", etc.)  (b) Using an `Application.InputBox` with a `Type` of 1 will at least ensure that the user enters a number, but you should still do validity checking before using it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx

Comment: I've updated with the Cint and it was working fine but now is failing again and I have not changed anything. I have updated the code on the main question

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to arise because you are obtaining a string value from the InputBox, but then comparing that to numeric values in cells H1:H12.

I recommend the following change to your code:

```
Sub Info()

    Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table_list_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow
    Dim inputData
    Dim inputData1 
    Dim rngLook As Range

    Set rngLook = Sheets("AutoZeroDatabase").Range("H1:I12")

    Set the_sheet = Sheets("Info")
    Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    Do
        inputData = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a number from 1 to 12 to select a month i.e. 1 for January", _
                                         Title:="Input Box Text", _
                                         Type:=1 + 4) 'Type 1 is number, 4 is boolean
        If TypeName(inputData) = "Boolean" Then
            If Not inputData Then
                inputData1 = "User refused to supply the month!!"
                Exit Do
            End If
        ElseIf inputData <> Int(inputData) Then
            MsgBox "Fractions of a month are not allowed!"
        ElseIf inputData < 1 Or inputData > 12 Then
            MsgBox "Months are numbered 1 to 12 - what am I meant to do with " & inputData & "?!?!?"
        Else
            inputData1 = Application.VLookup(inputData, rngLook, 2, False)
            If IsError(inputData1) Then
                 MsgBox "Something went very, very wrong - I couldn't find that value in the set of valid months!"
            End If
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = inputData1

    MsgBox ("Thank you for taking the time to update me :)")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do `Application.Vlookup` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`. The latter does not allow an error value to be returned, and you *may* need to trap for error value if the `inputData` value is not found in `rngLook`. Your validation sufficiently controls for the user-input side of things, but there's still some possibility that the worksheet itself is broken or manipulated, which would raise an error on the assignment to `inputData1`.

Comment: Thanks to Everyone , I also figure out I was getting an error because the range changed as 1 user added a column but know I got it :)

Comment: I have updated the answer based on @DavidZemens suggestions.  (I wish MSDN listed VLookup as one of the Application object's Methods!! )

Comment: @YowE3K there is also an `Application.Match` and `Application.Index` function, all of which can return Error type. Very useful to have these :) Instead of raising an error or handling with `On Error GoTo...` you can trap `If IsError(Application.Match(...` or assign the result to a variant and check that for error.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Oops - that reminded me - I changed `InputData1` to be a `Variant` while testing the change to use `Application.VLookup` but forgot to update the line in the answer - have now done so.